# Access kafka docker from outside

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have set a docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
        - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: ligato/kafka-arm64
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    expose:
      - "9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

Since I deployed on JETSON NX, I choose the image "ligato/kafka-arm64", and container info is

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS         PORTS                                                  NAMES
c8d890135148   ligato/kafka-arm64   "supervisord -n"         5 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds   2181/tcp, 9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9093->9093/tcp             kafka_docker_kafka_1
edba89568398   zookeeper:latest     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About an hour ago   Up 5 seconds   2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 8080/tcp   kafka_docker_zookeeper_1
```

then create a topic succesfully within the container, and run producer

```
docker exec -it c8d890135148 /bin/bash

./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic topic01

./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list kafka:9092 --topic topic01
```

and tried to type some letters, but outside the container not get anything...just stuck with anything.

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --topic topic01 --from-beginning
```

Anyone has experiences on this issue? Please share some comments with me!

After above, I tried to use latest kafka version outside container, kafka_2.13,2.8,0, and use the same command, but get

```
[2021-05-30 03:52:48,240] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-6086-1, groupId=console-consumer-6086] Bootstrap broker 127.0.0.1:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-05-30 03:52:48,347] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-6086-1, groupId=console-consumer-6086] Bootstrap broker 127.0.0.1:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-05-30 03:52:48,453] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-6086-1, groupId=console-consumer-6086] Bootstrap broker 127.0.0.1:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-05-30 03:52:48,558] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-6086-1, groupId=console-consumer-6086] Bootstrap broker 127.0.0.1:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

message repeating continuously.

Any comments for these 2 issues? Appreciated in advance!

Comment: Second issue - Kafka isn't running on port 9093 by default

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your reply. I wonder know how to correctly set the in-container port and out-container port. I think the default port for kafka is 9092, right? So I set the inside port as 9092 and outside port as 9093, so I make my outside kafka try to connect to port 9093, which is the outside port for the container, would that be any problem? Should I change outside port to 9092?

Comment: I was only referring to your comment - "I tried to use latest kafka version outside container, kafka_2.13,2.8,0, and use the same command"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that container supports those properties... And it hasn't been updated since early 2019, so if you want latest Kafka versions, look at Confluent or Bitnami Kafka images.

In any case, the listeners should bind externally to allow outside traffic

`KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093`

Aside: It also includes Zookeeper in itself, so you shouldn't have a separate Zookeeper container, and you should avoid mounting the Docker socket

Comment: After setting as you mentioned, still get the same messages

Comment: Like I said, I don't think that specific `ligato/kafka-arm64` image does what you want; specifically it appears to be a fork of the Spotify Kafka image that only uses advertised hostname + port, no listeners config environment variable at all